# How to print whole list after calling addfirst method?

Tags: java

How do i correct my addFirst method and also how can i make my removeFirst method work as it wont remove? How should i implement it?

```
public class LinkedList{
    public static  void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList l = new LinkedList();
        l.addFirst("c");
        //l.removeFirst("m");
        l.addFirst("b");
        System.out.println(l.first.data);
        System.out.println(l.first.data);
    }
    public Node first;
    static class Node {
        String data;
        Node next;
    }
    private void addFirst(String s){
        Node newNode = new Node();
        newNode.data=s;
        newNode.next=first;
        first=  newNode;
    }
    private void removeFirst(String s){
        //Node n1 = new Node();
        first.next = null;
    }
}
```

I want outcome to be :

```
b    
c
```

but only `b` is printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing the same value twice try this:

```
System.out.println(l.first.next.data);
```

In your linked list class, the first (or head) node will contain the next node so you'll have to call the first node and then call next nodes data.

Example:

```
LinkedList l = new LinkedList();
l.addFirst("c");
l.addFirst("b");
l.addFirst("z");
System.out.println(l.first.data);
System.out.println(l.first.next.data);
System.out.println(l.first.next.next.data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Return linkedlist by each function except main.
After adding or removing node you have to return the linkedlist in main function then you can print whole linkedlist

Comment: Can you explain a bit more how to do it?